# angle $0$ to $2\pi$ between two 3Dvectors

Tags: trigonometry

Ok this is for a computer game I'm learning to program with. How do you find angle between two normalized 3D vectors so that you get the resulting angle in the range $[0,2\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Using a simple Anti-cosine only gives values in the range $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: The angle between two vectors is in the interval $[0,\pi]$. To get a unique value in any of the ranges $[0,2\pi]$ or $[-\pi,\pi]$ you need a definition of which vector to start from (and which plane to perform the calculation in). Given that the simplest is probably the formula you're already using, and some rules to correct the result.

Comment: You may be interested in [Angle between two 3D vectors measured in a specific direction](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1139218). Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

#### Two dimensions

The angle $\theta$ between two unit vectors $a,b$ in **two** dimensions can be defined so that it lies in $[0,2\pi]$ or in $[-\pi,\pi]$, as follows:

1. Let $\theta$ be the least amount by which one has to turn $a$ counterclockwise so it becomes $b$. Then $\theta$ is in $[0,2\pi)$.
2. Let $\theta$ be the least amount by which one has to turn $a$ so it becomes $b$, choosing either counterclockwise (positive) or clockwise (negative) direction. Then $\theta$ is in $(-\pi,\pi]$ or in $[-\pi,\pi)$ depending on how you handle the edge case of $a,b$ being opposite to each other.

#### Three dimensions

Given two unit vectors $a,b$ in **three** dimensions, we don't have either of the options 1 or 2, because there isn't a well-defined concept of "clockwise". If you imagine a plane spanned by $a,b$ and try to follow the 2D approach, the  result depends on what side of the plane you look at. So, the only reasonable way to define the angle in 3D is

- Let $\theta$ be the least amount by which one has to turn $a$  so it becomes $b$.

Then $\theta$ is in $[0,\pi]$ and is given by the formula $\theta=\cos^{-1}(a\cdot b)$.

Comment: What if I select and fix the side of plane I look at as permanent for all calculations regarding these vectors? (selecting a plane is ok in my program's approach)

Comment: In order to fix the side of plane, you first have to fix the plane itself. Then you really have the 2D situation. You will be only ever considering vectors in that plane. So, introduce coordinates $x,y$ for that plane, and follow the 2D approach.

Comment: For the 2D formulas, see [Signed angle between 2 vectors?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/529555) and/or [Two 2d vector angle clockwise predicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/74307)