# Angle between two 3D vectors measured in a specific direction

Tags: vectors

Two normalized 3D vectors, $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, lie in the plane with the normal $\vec n$. By how much should $\vec a$ be rotated anti-clockwise around $\vec n$ to line up with $\vec b$?

The $acos$ of the dot product of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is not quite it, as that only returns the shortest angle, i.e. the rotation is either clockwise or anti-clockwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\vec a$, $\vec b$, $\vec n$ are oriented like standard basis vectors $i,j,k$, then the shortest angle is counterclockwise. Otherwise, it is clockwise. This suggests the following algorithm:

1. Compute the [triple product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) of $\vec a$, $\vec b$, $\vec n$, in this order.
2. If the triple product is positive, the answer is $\arccos \frac{\vec a\cdot\vec b }{|\vec a||\vec b|}$. Otherwise it is $2\pi-  \arccos \frac{\vec a\cdot\vec b }{|\vec a||\vec b|}$.

(The triple product is zero only when the three vectors lie in the same planar, which is not the case here).